# Can't connect Tor Network failed to establish network

Tags: help

failed to establish network and here are logs
26/04/2017 00:37:15 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
26/04/2017 00:37:15 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
26/04/2017 00:37:15 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
26/04/2017 00:37:15 ص.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
26/04/2017 00:37:15 ص.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
26/04/2017 00:37:15 ص.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
26/04/2017 00:38:46 ص.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 1F45542A24A61BF9408F1C05E0DCE4E29F2CBA11 at 5.9.146.203:443) 
26/04/2017 00:38:46 ص.200 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
26/04/2017 00:38:46 ص.200 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
26/04/2017 00:38:46 ص.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
26/04/2017 00:38:46 ص.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
26/04/2017 00:39:01 ص.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
26/04/2017 00:39:01 ص.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
26/04/2017 00:39:01 ص.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
26/04/2017 00:39:01 ص.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Comment: This is probably censorship: `[WARN] 8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE`. You should try using a bridges with pluggable transports.